# Codeigniter 2 - Form Validation Custom Rules

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I'm working with Codeigniter 2.2.5 and PHP 5.6

I want to validate the user input with the codeiginter functions. This is the normal way:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('mail', 'E-Mail', 'required|trim|xss_clean|strip_tags');
```

Here I would like to add a function that checks whether the e-mail address is contained in a defined list.

There is a callback function for custom rules, but this only works in the controller class. I'm in a third party library class.

Like

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'callback_username_check');
```

Does anybody have an idea on how to achieve this with CodeIgniter 2 or do I have to check it on my own and create a custom error message?

I know that in CodeIgniter 3 there are new functionalities, but unfortunately, I have to work with CodeIgniter 2.

Comment: then just make that rule where you're creating  the rule

Comment: custom rules only work if you are inside a controller

Answer (score 1):

In codeigniter 2 it's not possible to use a callback method from outside a controller. So if you are in a library or in a model, you have to do a workaround.

What you should do is have a helper function that you load prior to initialization of the model/library you are in. Then you treat it as a normal PHP function and not a 'callback'.

Like this:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'username_check');
```

Where `username_check` is the function you have loaded in the helper.

Anyways, there is a difference between data manipulation and data validation. Validation only should happen in a controller. So you may have to refactor your code. This will help you in the long run.

Comment: I've added an answer, in the comment section arent enough characters.

Answer (score 0):

@Pedro Martins

Thank you. I created a helper class and implemented the check function. The function is called correctly and the value to be checked is pass trough it. In my check function I return TRUE if the value is ok, otherwise FALSE.

LibraryCode:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('mail', 'E-Mail', 'checkMail');
```

Helper Class:

```
function checkMail($value)
{
    if($value == ".....") //if clause works correctly
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

However, the form-validation function always returns TRUE, no matter what my custom helper-check function returns.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('mail', 'E-Mail', 'checkMail');       

    //if form validation false -> show form again
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        // ...... is never triggered
    }
    else //if form validation success, proceed
    {
        // ......
    }
```

The program structure is unfortunately so given, therefore I can not locate my code in the controller.

Comment: Refactor your code, so that only in CONTROLLERS you do data validation.
The workaround I talked about is not good long term.